# OpenGL left-handed coordinate system

Tags: opengl, matrix, projection

I'm writing a 3D OpenGL app and I'm having problems with my vertex translation matrix.

Here's my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4     vInPos;

uniform mat4    kWorld;
uniform mat4    kProj;

void main( void )
{
    vec4 world_pos = kWorld * vInPos;
    gl_Position = kProj * world_pos;
}
```

All my matrices are stored row major and I'm using a left handed perspective matrix as my projection matrix.

The problem is, when I translate a vertex by my matrix, it moves in the wrong direction on both the X and Y axes, and is flipped. So translating by `(100.0f,100.0f,100.0f)` moves my vertex the correct way on the Z axis (away from the camera), but to the left on the X axis (backwards) and down on the Y axis (backwards).

Here's what it currently looks like: [image: screenshot]

The FPS counter should be up and to the right, instead of down to the left. It should also obviously not be mirrored. Based on what I've read, this is happening because OpenGL by default uses the right-handed coordinate system, but I'm not sure what I can do to fix this.

I found a few articles that try to explain it, but I couldn't find any solutions for what to do. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199291/left-handed-calculations-in-opengl) mentions that the OpenGL spec shows what the coordinate system expected, but after looking, I didn't see how that helped me.

EDIT:
For reference, my projection matrix code is based on the [DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205350(v=vs.85).aspx).

EDIT:
Per Nicol Bolas' suggestion, I'm now using the matrix from [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), but I'm getting the same results.

---

Here's the code I'm using to set my matrices:

```
/* Vertex data for reference
float vertices[] =
{
    {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
    {5.0f,0.0f,0.0f},
    {0.0f,5.0f,0.0f},
    {5.0f,5.0f,0.0f},
}; */    
float worldf[16];
float projf[16];
float fov       = 60.0f;
float aspect    = 1280.0f/720.0f;
float near      = 1.0f;
float far       = 1000.0f;
float f         = 1.0f/tanf( (fov*6.2831f/360.0f)/2.0f );

/* Build world matrix */
memset(worldf, 0, sizeof(worldf));
worldf[0] = worldf[5] = worldf[10] = worldf[15] = 1.0f;
worldf[12] = 100.0f;
worldf[13] = 100.0f;
worldf[14] = -100.0f;

/* Build perspective matrix */
memset(projf, 0, sizeof(projf));
projf[0] = f/aspect;
projf[5] = f;
projf[10] = (far+near)/(near-far);
projf[14] = (2.0f*far*near)/(near-far);
projf[11] = -1.0f;

glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, projf);
glUniformMatrix4fv(world_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, worldf);
```

Using this code, my text doesn't show up at all.

EDIT: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using OpenGL 2.0 on OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: I once heard something like, to switch from left-handed to right-handed coordinate systems, just invert one of the axes.  (ie: instead of (1,1,1), you might have (1,1,-1).)  They said it didn't matter much which one you flip, but obviously some are better for a given desired result than others.

Comment: I've tried inverting each of the axes at a time. Flipping the X or Y axes didn't affect the outcome, and flipping the Z eliminated my rendering altogether. I've turned off culling, so it's not that my draw call was culled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a left-handed perspective matrix

Stop doing that.

Equally importantly, the output of the projection matrix (clip-space) is *different* for OpenGL and D3D. You can't just take a D3D projection matrix, transpose it, and expect that GLSL will accept the output just fine.

So again, look up [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) and use that matrix.

---

> Per Nicol Bolas' suggestion, I'm now using the matrix from gluPerspective, but I'm getting the same results.

You're likely also using a bunch of other left-handed matrices. Your model-to-camera matrix needs to be right-handed. Also, your vertex data needs to be right-handed as well. Alternatively, you can try to convert from left-handed space to right-handed, but I wouldn't advise it unless you had no other choice.

---

```
float f = 1.0f/tanf(fov/2.0f);
```

`fov` is an angle in degrees. `tanf` takes an angle in *radians*. The `tanf` of `30.0f` is a negative number, which means your frustum scale in your perspective matrix is negative. That effectively inverts the X and Y axes of your view.

What you really need is this:

```
float f = 1.0f/tanf((fov * 6.2831f / 360.0f ) / 2.0f);
```

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally typed right instead of left. I'm using left-handed perspective matrices. I updated my original question.

Comment: I'm no longer using any left-handed anything. My matrix is built using the math from gluPerspective, and my world matrix is just an identity matrix with `worldMatrix[12] = 100, worldMatrix[13] = 100, worldMatrix[14] = 100`. My 4 vertices are `vertices[] = { {0,0}, {50,0}, {0,50}, {50,50} }`. I've turned off culling just to make sure they aren't being culled whenever I try making changes, and I have two index buffers, one with clockwise and one with counter-clockwise winding, and I've tested both. Nothing seems to change the outcome.

Comment: @Kyle: The camera-space that the standard OpenGL perspective matrix sets up has -Z in front of the camera, and +Z behind it. So if you're translating your vertices by 100, and you're still seeing them, then you've still got some bad matrices somewhere. Can you just add the actual matrices that you're using to your answer, along with the glUniformMatrix code you're using to render with them?

Comment: I've updated my question with the actual code I'm using. I'm still seeing the same results.

Comment: When I transpose my world matrix, my text disappears. I wasn't transposing it because the [OpenGL Documentation](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) says that the transform should be in indices 13, 14, and 15, which they are in my matrix. But regardless, transposing made my text disappear. I have a feeling I'm missing some small detail, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Kyle: Your code is very confused. Your perspective matrix is row-major, but your model-to-camera is column-major. You need to pick a convention and stick with it. That being said, I see what is likely the source of your problem. See my updated edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4179/discussion-between-kyle-and-nicol-bolas)